# Wiggly riddles, here we are!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Here is a riddle. Can you solve it?

> I don't drink from my mouth 
> but the other way around 
> Long, long, long 
> Things can go down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> A river?

I don't drink from my mouth

but the other way around

> The source of a river (where it "drinks") is located on the opposite end of what's called the mouth of the river which is where rivers run off into the ocean, a lake or another river.

Long, long, long

> Rivers are all more or less long.

Things can go down

> The river's water (or anything else it's carrying) can only ever go down, never up.